# .Net MVC View Not Trigger Javascript with Hostname

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, webserver

I am facing this problem. If I type localhost/web/search, the webpage is able to trigger javascript but if I type hostname/web/search, it doesn't trigger the submit event in javascript.

I have included the partial code as below.

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-3.0.0.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-3.0.0.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetFields(_ReportType) {
        var procemessage = "<option value='0'> Please wait...</option>";
        $("#ddlFields").html(procemessage).show();     

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetSearchFields", "Search")',
            data: { iReportID: _ReportType },
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                var markup = "<option value='0'>---Select Fields---</option>";
                for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                    markup += "<option value=" + data[x].Value + ">" + data[x].Text + "</option>";
                }
                $("#ddlFields").html(markup).show();
            },
            error: function (reponse) {
                alert("error : " + reponse);
            }
        });
    }

$(document).ready(function () {      
        $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {            
            $.ajax({   
                url: '@Url.Action("WebGrids", "Search")',   
                type: 'GET',
                data: {
                    //'strQueryType': 'GGI_Lot_ID',
                    'strReport': $("#ddlReport").find("option:selected").text(),
                    'strQueryType': $("#ddlFields").find("option:selected").text(),
                    //'strValue': '110723233'
                    'strValue': $("#taSearchValues").text()
                },
                success: function (vHtml) {   
                            $("#dvShow").html("");   
                            $("#dvShow").html(vHtml);   
                },
                error: function (reponse) {
                    //alert("123");
                    alert("error : " + reponse);
                }
            });   
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: what is hostname ?

Comment: The web server name

Comment: "If I type"....type where? " it doesn't trigger the submit event"...what submit event? There's no form here, and the code above is not related to submitting a form as far as we can see, it makes some separate ajax call. It's hard to know how the code you've given us relates to the problem. How is the "GetFields" function triggered, and how is it related to typing anything or triggering submit events?

Comment: And why have you included jQuery twice in your page? You only need it once. Use the full-fat .js version in development when you might need to do debugging, and the .min.js version for live deployment when it's more important to have a small file size.

Comment: I have edited my question to add in the code, both the javascript is not triggered. I can see the error when do debugging, "the value of the property '$' is null of undefined, not a function object"